# Cannot yum install java CENTOS

Tags: centos, yum

Every time I want to install java on my machine, I get the following error. I tried this:

```
yum clean metadata
yum cleanall
```

But I am still getting the following error!

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: google. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score -1):

Things went back to normal when I removed: `/etc/yum.repos.d/google.repo`